# How to change background with php and css

Tags: php, html, css

I have a php and html code and I have this

```
<?php

if (!$_SESSION['login']) {
    $favicon = 'favicon.ico';
    $logo = 'logo';
    $bg = 'bg';
} elseif ($_SESSION['sex'] === 'Hombre') {
    $favicon = 'faviconh.ico';
    $logo = 'logoh';
    $bg = 'bgh';
} else {
    $favicon = 'faviconm.ico';
    $logo = 'logom';
?>

<body>

etc
```

How I can put the bg var to put the background image with the if?

I try to put <?php echo 'background-image id="'.$bg.'"'; ?>> but doesn't work.

I have 3 Css so in the if when I put bg or bgh or bgm I am taking one background image or another or another.

Ant solution?

The css is

```
.bg {
backgroun-image: URL ('../img/bg.jpg');
}

.bgh {
backgroun-image: URL ('../img/bgh.jpg');
}

.bgm {
backgroun-image: URL ('../img/bgm.jpg');
}
```

Comment: do you want to set background image for your page?

Comment: set background image but with the php var $bg

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, but result css is strange.

You can assign id to DOM like:

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

And in css part, you write something like:

```
#test {
   background-image: url('path/to/image.jpg');
}
```

So, result:

```
<?php

$bg_id = 'bg_for_man';

?>

<style>
   #bg_for_man {
      background-image: url('/images/bg_for_man.jpg');
   }
</style>

<body id="<?php print($bg_id); ?>">
   <!-- Some html -->
</body>
```

Comment: Yes but it works with login so I need only one id for each bg

Answer (score 0):

you can it with this

```
$bg= '<style type="text/css">
body
{
    background-image:url('image URL');
}
</style>';
echo $bg;
```

Comment: But I want three different background and with the if put one or another one or other

Comment: copy the same code in the other two variables also and use it as you like

Comment: But I need only one id and put $bg_id an this id have 3 images

Comment: Are there any solution like background: id="'.$bg_id.'"

Comment: your question is not clear,how you want the output look like?

Answer (score 0):

I finally put it correctly!

I do this

```
<body <?php echo 'id="'.$bg.'"' ?>
```

It works perfectly!